# Compare two XML db schema in HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, schema, heidisql

I exported two DB schema from server through phpmyadmin in XML format.
First XML schema is of testing database, and the second xml schema is of live database.
I want to compare these database schema, based theme comparison I would make the changes in live database.
**How can I compare thsese XML database schemea in phpmyadmin or HeidiSQL?**
I would appreciate any kind of help or support.

Comment: For anyone who wonders how to export to XML from mysql. To quote Anse from https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=76 
1) Go to the data tab   2) right click in the grid    3) choose "Export data"
4) choose filetype "XML"   5) choose a filename and click "Save"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HeidiSQL can export structure and data, but there is no compare feature yet.

My tool of choice for comparing any type of file is BeyondCompare from https://www.scootersoftware.com . This is how it looks when you compare two .sql files (this can of course also be done with xml files):

[image]